# Is it possible to have one HTML document split into MIME chunks?

Tags: http, mime-types, mime

I have a HTTP response. 
Is there any way to send it, in two MIME chunks?

For example: in HTTP response I have:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Example</title>
  <body>Some Body</body>
</html>
```

I want to send something like this:

```
--SOME_MIME_boundary
    <html>
      <head><title>Example</title>
--SOME_MIME_boundary
      <body>Some Body</body>
    </html>
--SOME_MIME_boundary
```

Is this possible to have one html document splitted into couple of MIME chunks?
I want browsers (on client end) to recognize that thoose 2 chunks are one html document and properly display it.

If it is possible, give me some simple http response example (with headers etc), please.
I simply don't know how to construct that HTTP response.

If you want to know why I need this check:
[HTTP - how to send multiple pre-cached gzipped chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740034/http-how-to-send-multiple-pre-cached-gzipped-chunks)

Thank You!

Comment: Surely it is possible but what are you asking? If the spec allows it, if some API supports it..?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? XY: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: If this is possible please paste some example response (headers, bouandries etc). I dont need api. I will construct that response on my own. But I don't know how to chop something into two mime chunks. Browser must treat that two chunks as one document.