# Sending precompressed data through Netty's HTTP handlers

Tags: java, gzip, netty

I have a scenario where a Netty server has a GZIP'd buffer, and I'd like to send it as part of a chunked response without inflating/deflating.

By way of illustration: imagine I have three parts:

- `ChannelBuffer jsonp = "callback("`,
- `ChannelBuffer gzippedData = <gzipped bytes>`,
- `ChannelBuffer jsonpend = ")"`

I'd like `HttpContentCompressor` to skip `gzippedData`, but handle the other chunks.

I don't see an obvious way to do this after reading the code. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to have your own version of HttpContentCompressor for this. By default it will not do what you want.

Comment: Interesting link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740034/http-how-to-send-multiple-pre-cached-gzipped-chunks#comment27831334_16740510 - turns out only Opera supports this.