# Sharing DEFLATE-compressed data chunks between streaming HTTP clients

Tags: node.js, http, zlib, server-sent-events, deflate

I want to serve some streaming data over HTTP. Additionally, I'd like to compress the data to save bandwidth. I can trivially compress each streaming response separately, but in my case, the data stream is largely the same for every single client (fanout), so it seems like a waste of CPU time to compress the same data for each connection. My plan is to compress each chunk of streaming data preemptively, so clients who connect at any time can start reading the next chunk (this comes at the cost of reduced compression efficiency, but as long as the individual chunks of data are big enough, this should be fine).

Compliant HTTP clients are apparently supposed to be able to accept multiple gzipped files in a `Content-Encoding: gzip` response, [but the answers to this question indicate web browsers do not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740034/http-how-to-send-multiple-pre-cached-gzipped-chunks). However, from my understanding of DEFLATE/zlib, you can instead send [`Z_FULL_FLUSH` `0x0000FFFF`](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced) bytes to reset the stream which should serve the same effect of individually decompressible chunks.

I've set up a simple POC in node.js that streams a message as a Server Sent Events stream, but I can't get a web-browser to read the data; it will open the connection, but will never flush the data. I'm using `Z_NO_COMPRESSION` for simplicity.

```
var http, zlib, gzip, numClients;
http = require('http');
zlib = require('zlib');
gzip = zlib.createDeflateRaw({
  flush: zlib.Z_SYNC_FLUSH,
  level: zlib.Z_NO_COMPRESSION
});
numClients = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  if (numClients > 0) {
    gzip.write("data: hi\n\n");
  }
}, 1000);
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.socket.setTimeout(Infinity);
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Content-Encoding': 'deflate',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'identity',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  });

  res.write('\x78\x01'); // write zlib magic number
  gzip.pipe(res);
  numClients++;
  res.on('close', function(){
    numClients--;
    gzip.unpipe(res);
  });
  res.on('error', function(){
    numClients--;
    gzip.unpipe(res);
  });
}).listen(8080);
numClients++;
gzip.pipe(process.stdout);
```

And a simple client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>hi</title>

<script>
var es = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/");
es.addEventListener('data', console.log);
es.addEventListener('open', console.log);
es.addEventListener('error', console.log);
</script>
```

Bytes look like this, (`curl -N localhost:8080` piped through `xxd`):

```
0000000: 7801 000a 00f5 ff64 6174 613a 2068 690a  x......data: hi.
0000010: 0a00 0000 ffff 000a 00f5 ff64 6174 613a  ...........data:
0000020: 2068 690a 0a00 0000 ffff 000a 00f5 ff64   hi............d
0000030: 6174 613a 2068 690a 0a00 0000 ffff 000a  ata: hi.........
0000040: 00f5 ff64 6174 613a 2068 690a 0a00 0000  ...data: hi.....
0000050: ffff 000a 00f5 ff64 6174 613a 2068 690a  .......data: hi.
0000060: 0a00 0000 ffff 000a 00f5 ff64 6174 613a  ...........data:
```

Do I need to add extra framing for a DEFLATE decompressor to detect the flush points?

EDIT: I added the [zlib magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050260/what-does-a-zlib-header-look-like) to make the http stream a valid DEFLATE stream, but
the web browser still won't flush the blocks. However, piping the `gzip` stream back through `zlib.createInflate()` works fine if the magic number is added. I also know that the http stream isn't being buffered because `curl -N localhost:8080` will display the raw bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't actually with DEFLATE, zlib, or any actual framing, but with the `EventSource` client. Embarrassing.

The [Server-Sent Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) defines three events on the `EventSource` object, `open`, `error`, and `message`. `message` fires for all messages emitted on the stream. Any other events subscribed to with `addEventListener` serve as sugar for filtering by server-specified event types, using the `event` syntax, e.g.

```
event: <event-name>
data: ...
```

In other words, changing this line in `client.html`:

```
es.addEventListener('data', console.log);
```

to

```
es.addEventListener('message', console.log);
```

Will cause the web browser to correctly log all the "hi" messages from the server as they are flushed.

Re: compression, the code in the question does generate a valid DEFLATE stream, so it's all good on that part.

I think it could also be adapted to a `gzip` stream with some header changes, but the only real change of gzip over DEFLATE is the integrity check at the end of the stream, as mentioned In Mark Adler's answer. In my case, I don't have a stream end, so I can never send a checksum anyway, negating any benefits of gzip.

Answer (score 0):

The zlib stream needs to be terminated by a last block and an integrity check.  The last block is signified by the "last bit" set at the start of the block.  In this case since the next-to-last block is a stored block, putting you at a byte boundary, the last block can be 01 00 00 ff ff.

Then you need an Adler-32 check on the uncompressed data as the last four bytes of the stream, following the last block.

Comment: How does the "last block" bit and integrity check play with `Z_FULL_FLUSH` and my unbounded stream? Do I need the last block + check after every chunk of data? Will the decompressor read beyond the integrity check for another block? If I'm understanding you correctly, my bytestream should look like `(magic)((stored block)*(01 00 00 ff ff)(Adler-32))*`.

Comment: The last block and check just goes at the end.  So in your notation, `(magic)(full flush blocks)*(01 00 00 ff ff)(adler-32)`.  The full flush is needed to assure that the last block with data ends at a byte boundary.

Comment: You can pre-compute the Adler-32 check for each of the prepared blocks, and combine them when you build the complete stream using `adler32_combine()`.